# SQL Server - Select YEAR error

Tags: sql-server

Currently using SQL Server 2008. In an effort to debug some bad date data being processed, the following code was written with an example of the bad data.

```
SELECT ISDATE('10-22-002')
SELECT YEAR('10-22-002')
```

Running the statements on database A, the results are: '1' and '2002'.

Running the statements on database B, the results are: '1' and an error.

The date format is MDY on all sessions before running the statements.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1
>   Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Everything I'm able to find says the date format is set at either server or session level. Is there a setting at the DB level for this?

Comment: both are the same versions ?? are different from each other..by executing both this statements 1st one giving 1 as result 2nd one error if you have 2002 it will give year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `'10-22-002'` as a `datetime`.

```
SELECT YEAR(cast('10-22-002' as datetime))
```

Comment: SUPER - worked like a charm.  I'm still baffled as to why the SELECT YEAR function works over one DB but not another while in Management Studio.